# having problems with ng-repeat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am working on a Rails 3.2.11 app using angular 1.0.5.

Currently, a user will select a Cycle from a dropdown, and that will return a bunch of JSON from my controller using ng-resource. 
Here is the method

```
$scope.update = function(cycleId) {
    Cycle.get({action: cycleId}, function(resource) {
        $scope.selectedCycle = resource;
        $scope.tasks = resource.tasks;
        $scope.newTask = {cycle_id: resource.cycle.id};
    });
};
```

Here is an example of what json my controller is returning, which is 'resource' in above function: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/01ffe5a37e370661f6fb

Basically I am needing to use ng-repeat twice (one of them nested) using angulars ng-repeat, so that I can get the task_type_name in there as a header. I'm getting some weird interesting results. See the shorted code in my view below and the full thing [here](https://gist.github.com/ruevaughn/df591c158311362935b9)

```
 <section ng-repeat="(task_type_name,task_type) in tasks ">
   <h2>{{task_type_name}}</h2>
     <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Task Name</th> 
        </tr>
        <section id="task-edit">
          <tr ng-repeat="task in task_type">
            <td>
              <%= link_to "{{task.name}}", '', "ng-click"=>"toggleShowHistory(task.id)" %>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </section
     </table>
```

So my is occuring at this part here

```
<section id="task-edit">
  <tr ng-repeat="task in task_type">
```

If I try to combine that section and tr, OR change tr to ANYTHING but a tr, {{task}} no longer becomes available.

```
<section class="task-edit" ng-repeat="task in task_type">
    {{task}} is available right here
    <tr>
       {{task}} is not available right here
      <td>
        {{task}} is not avaiable right here
     </td>
    </tr>
 </section>
```

I tested the same concept on the first loop, and it seems to be fine on that loop just not the second, nested loop.

I'm assuming it has something to do with the scope. But i'm just not getting it.
Also, if you have any tips, i'm very new to angular and would love them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a demo, and I am not seeing any issue. Please check your data source and make sure you plug in the `tasks` value of the json.

You need to change the nested `section` to `tbody`.

<kbd>**[Demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QLwqZ/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the comment and fiddle, I should probably use fiddle more. The problem is when I move the ng-repeat to to section, see your updated fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/QLwqZ/3/

Comment: You need to change the nested section to tbody.

Comment: Is that because angular rendering it as a template? or why is that the case?